# AJAX loading of blog posts with Masonry.js issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, silverstripe, masonry

I'm not sure if anybody else is getting this problem. But I am using Masonry.js on my blog holder page as well as an AJAX 'read more' button to load new posts without refresh.

When I load new posts however they are applied on top of the other ones. This is because Masonry.js has applied absolute positioning on the blog posts that existed on page load, but not the ones newly added with AJAX.

Does anybody know how to perhaps reinitialise Masonry.js to make it re-run for the new blog entries?

Thanks, if you need any more info ask me.

Comment: You could try to [add them to Masonry itself](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended)

Comment: Share some of your code. How can we help you without knowing what your doing?

Comment: Well the question is whether there is a way to apply the masonry.js position value on elements that have been added post page load? I have no code to support this. I tried converting the new posts to jQuery objects and append them using the [append method](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended) but that has not worked. It looks like they were added to the layout but the position value was not applied.

`items = [];
  $('.item').each(function() {
   items.push($(this));
  });` to create a jquery array of the objects.

Comment: `$grid = $('#blog-container').masonry({
   columnWidth: 80
  });
    // create new item elements
    var $items = items;

    // append items to grid
    $grid.append( $items )
     // add and lay out newly appended items
     .masonry( 'appended', $items );` to append them. This did not work

Comment: @JackO'Connor - Please edit your question and put your code in there rather than pasting it into a comment. This will help clarify the question.